# Detectar click no mesmo item dinâmico e não dinâmico

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quando clico no item, a função altera a *class* desse item para ele poder ser detectado pela outra função ao clicar.

O problema é que quando eu utilizo o `.click`, o *click* é detectado normalmente, mas quando eu clico novamente (já com a class alterada), não detecta esse *click*.

E quando eu uso o `.on`, não funciona nem quando eu clico pela primeira vez.

HTML

```
<div class="options">
     <ul>
         <li><a href="#" class="com-estoque">ativar</a></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

Uso a função abaixo para abrir e fechar o menu onde está o link. Acredito que o que está dando conflito é esse `stopPropagation()` , mas não tenho certeza. Teria alguma forma de contornar esse problema?

JS

```
$(".options").click(function(e) {
    $(this).find('ul').toggle();

    e.stopPropagation();
});
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
    $('.options ul').hide();
});

$('.pagina-produtos-admin').on('click', '.sem-estoque', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $(this).parents('.produto').addClass('semestoque');
    $(this).removeClass('sem-estoque').addClass('com-estoque').html('ativar');
});

$('.pagina-produtos-admin').on('click', '.com-estoque', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $(this).parents('.produto').removeClass('semestoque');
    $(this).removeClass('com-estoque').addClass('sem-estoque').html('marcar como fora de estoque');
});
```

Comment: Tá funcionando normal amigo.

Comment: Agora que tu mencionou, fui testar em um editor online e funciona mesmo. Não sei pq não está funcionando no meu código.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creio que seja isto que está querendo fazer: clicar no link para alternar a classe e o texto sem esconder a `<ul>`. Fiz uma modificação no seu código para ficar mais preciso e enxuto:

```js
$('.options').click(function(e) {
    $(this).find('ul').toggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$('.options').find('.sem-estoque, .com-estoque').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

   $(this)
   .toggleClass('sem-estoque com-estoque')
   .html( $(this).hasClass("com-estoque") ? 'ativar' : 'marcar como fora de estoque' )
   .parents('.produto')
   .removeClass('semestoque');

});

$(document).on('click', function(e) {
    $('.options ul').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pagina-produtos-admin">
   <div class="options">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="com-estoque">ativar</a></li>
        </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

O segundo parâmetro no método `.on` do jQuery, como você usou é justamente para este tipo de problema. Criar *listeners* de evento em elementos dinâmicos.

Por exemplo:

```
$('.my-element').on('click', function() {
  alert('Clicado!');
});

// Criamos o elemento de forma dinâmica:
$('<div>', { 'class': 'my-element' }).appendTo('body');
```

Mas se fizermos:

```
$('body').on('click', '.my-element', function() {
  alert('Clicado!');
});

// Criamos o elemento de forma dinâmica:
$('<div>', { 'class': 'my-element' }).appendTo('body');
```

O evento irá disparar normalmente ao *click* do botão.
Para saber mais, consulte a [documentação do método `.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data).

---

Provavelmente o seu erro ocorre por que, de acordo com o código enviado acima, você não incluiu o cifrão do jQuery:

```
('.pagina-produtos-admin').on('click', '.sem-estoque', function(e) {
  // [...]
```

O correto, então, seria:

```
$('.pagina-produtos-admin').on('click', '.sem-estoque', function(e) {
  // [...]
```

Comment: Estou usando o cifrão no código completo, foi um erro ao copiar para cá. Testei o mesmo código em editor online e ta normal, não sei por que não funciona no código completo. Nenhuma outra função está utilzando essas mesmas classes.

Comment: Você tem um erro no console? Qual o código completo?

Comment: Encontrei o motivo do problema. Alterei o post com mais informações